Discrepancy Between iTunes Search API and App Store Results on Device
I am using the iTunes Search API (https://itunes.apple.com/search) to retrieve search results based on a keyword. However, the results returned by the API differ significantly from those I see when searching on the App Store directly on a real device.
For example, when I search for the keyword "example" using the API, I get a certain set of results. When I search for the same keyword on the App Store on my iPhone, the results are different in terms of both the apps listed and their order.
Questions:

Is there a way to retrieve search results via the API that match those from the App Store on a real device?

Are there any additional parameters or different endpoints that should be used to get more accurate results?


Additional Information:

I am specifying entity=software in my API request.

Any insights or suggestions on how to align the API results with the App Store search results on the device would be greatly appreciated.
Perform a search using the iTunes Search API:
curl -X GET "https://itunes.apple.com/search?country=us&term=example&entity=software"

Perform a search using the same keyword on the App Store on an iPhone.
